# Out of Stock Images - grey out if products are out of stock in magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to display product which are out of stock in gray shaded background with blur effect

when any product goes out of stock then it should display with gray shade or slide blur.

From which file i can change the code?Please help me if any body know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize from here:

app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Here is code:

```
<?php if (!$product->isSaleable()): {
     echo '<style>.category-products li.item .product-image img{ opacity:0.6;
     filter: alpha(opacity=60); } </style>';

 } endif;?>
```

you can place this code at end of your file.